# Can't find all machine name on local network

Tags: c#, networking, ip-address, host, subnet

We're trying to obtain all ip addresses and hostnames of machines on local network, we have a display box(BrightSign box) which is connected to local network and we want to have all information about that box. We can find ip address of it, but cannot get host name. So we can't determine which ip adresses is assigned to that box. (We can learn the ip address of the box by using its own program; but we want to detect automatically)

here the code we use in c#
`

```
    public void scan(string subnet)
    {
        Ping myping;
        PingReply reply;
        IPAddress addr;
        IPHostEntry host;


        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            string subnetn = "." + i.ToString();
            myping = new Ping();
            //string data = "aa";
            //byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            //PingOptions optionss = new PingOptions(64, true);
            int timeout = 1000;
            reply = myping.Send(subnet + subnetn);

            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                try {
                    addr = IPAddress.Parse(subnet+subnetn);
                    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);
                    txtHosts.AppendText(subnet + subnetn + host.HostName.ToString()+"\n");                           
                }
                catch { 

                }
            }
        }

    }`
```

if we use this code,  system can detect all ip but not host names belongs to telephone and the box i mentioned.
Briefly, we need to have all machine name and ip addresses on local network.
So, do you guys have any idea what's the problem and what can we do to solve this issue. We made some research and tried some ways. We tried to send ping the ip address which we cannot take the hostname and we realized that if ttl of machine is set to 64, we cannot take the hostname, but if its ttl is 128, we can manage to learn the hostname, i also adjusted ping settings to test this challenge, but i still have problem.

I am looking forward to hearing your response.
Thank you all.

Comment: You must have some sort of loop in your ip routing tables.  TTL is an abbreviation for Time-To-Live. Every time your Ping goes through a router or server the ttl is decreased by 1.A router or server will not forward an IP when the ttl reaches zero.  So on a local net your ttl should never be greater than ~5.You may have two PCs/Routers set with the same IP address.  Your IP mask may be set incorrectly.I would start by opening an cmd.exe window and perform the Ping manually.  Check the ttl and make sure you are getting a low number.Try pin with both IP address and host name and compare results.

Comment: We are observing this result: reply from x.x.x.x: bytes:32 time 3ms ttl=64, ping statistics for x.x.x.x: %0 lost, approximate round trip times in millisecond: minimum:1ms, maximum: 3 ms, average=1ms.

Comment: If you are setting the ttl to 64 and seeing the ping response as 64 then you  are going through one hop (one server or router).  It should also work with 32, 16, and even 8.  It does not make sense it would not work with 32.;  The ttl has nothing to do with issue.  Setting ttl to a large number when you are failing is just creating routing loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Machine name could be DNS or NETBIOS or something else. I recommend you check out NMAP and see what it can do. If you want to emulate that, you can ask about a specific requirement. For example, getting a DNS name means querying the DNS server, a computer wont reply with a name just from an ICMP ping. If the computer security settings allow it, you can do a netbios query, or use WMI, or if you are in a domain, query the domain server.

I don't know what brightsign is, but there is no law that says a device must have a DNS name, some appliances just use IP address and thats it. Also there's no law that says a device must respond to ping or any other protocol.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the information. I think i cannot explain myself well, we  can obtain the hostname and ip address from this box's program; and we can send ping and get  success result via cmd. but we are developing a program which can automatically detect ip and host informations and make a decision about which ip adress is assigned to that box. For example, the hostname of this box starts with "BrightSign" and when wee see that, we must say yes this is the box, and box's ip adress is that. But we cannot do it with c# even though we can get success result from ping which we send in cmd.

Comment: You can use the MAC Address which contains the manufacture, model, serial number to determine the type of device.  MAC is return in a Ping (ARP Response).  You can see the ARP table from cmd.exe window by typing ARP -A.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I said. If you do a DNS lookup to get the ip address and then ping it, getting the response as in your code will not confirm that you are pinging the correct device. This is no different to CMD. Ping a dns address in the CMD, if the DNS is wrong, it will still say it successfully pinged the device if another device has that IP address. Using MAC address as per jdweng's advice will help but there are other issues. This is more complicated than you seem to realise. Again I recommend you download NMAP and play with it to see what port scanning is like.